# Internet disconnects from server as soon as i connect freeradius server box to client computer

Tags: coovachilli

I m trying to setup a captive portal using freeradius, coovachilli on Ubuntu 14 server(32 bit)

After the complete installation, the internet works fine on ubuntu server box with both freeradius and coovachilli running.

But when I connect client pc to second Ethernet card , the internet gets disconnected from server box and ofcourse the client machine also do not get the internet. However the client machine gets the IP 10.1.0.3 from dhcp.

I've reinstall the OS and the complete captive portal setup 5 times but the same pblm..

Where am I going wrong?

Note
When I install the OS my ethernet cards gets name as em1 and pp251. But I run apt get remove boisdevname and then update-initramfs -u to get the device name as eth0 and eth1. However the inbuilt card gets the name eth1 and the pci Ethernet card as eth0. So I put my internet cable to the second card so as to make my eth0 as WAN.

Comment: I believe you need to post it on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/tour)